# Hamming decoding

Tags: cryptography

I have a small notebook that copies the example of the McEliece cryptosystem found [here](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/ctcmcel.html). The page omits the step used to decode $y'$. Does Mathematica contain any facilities for using Hamming decoding? If so, how do I access them and how do I use them? If it doesn't have them, are there any Mathematica packages out there that do?

Comment: Take a look at the following MathSource resource: [Error-correcting codes with Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5085/). It contains an implementation of Hamming coding (`HammingCode`) and decoding (`DecHammingCode`) functions.